# MYSQL query - INSERT INTO with a CASE in the SELECT?

Tags: mysql, insert, case

I'm trying to INSERT multiple rows into one table (`wp_terms`) from another table (`a_schools`).  The catch is...

In my custom table, I have three columns to consider `toggle`, `city`, `school`.  If `toggle = 1`, then I need to have the city as part of the result along with the school.  ELSE just the school.

So...

```
toggle | city      | school
NULL   | Lafayette | McCutcheon  (would read = McCutcheon)
1      | Lafayette | Jefferson   (would read = Lafayette Jeff)
```

I've tried several instances, though many searches.

```
insert into wp_terms (name)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (toggle= 1) THEN concat(city, ' ',school)
        ELSE school
    END as schoolName 
FROM a_schools
WHERE NOT EXISTS
```

Comment: Other than the unnecessary column alias and the unfinished `NOT EXISTS` clause, what problem are you having with this query?

Comment: @Nick Syntax error with the NOT EXISTS clause.  I've made several attempts at this query, always getting a syntax error, mostly around CASE and concat.

I thought I would need the alias for the concat, as most examples I saw ended with that.

Comment: @Akina  I apologize for not stating this initially.  The NOT EXISTS is because I already have 400+ rows of data in wp_terms, as well as 410 rows of data in a_schools.  I want INSERT the 300 or so from a_schools that aren't already in wp_terms without duplicating the ones already there.  

The reality is I've spent more time trying to figure out the query than it would've taken me to type the data in the other table, but I also like learning new queries.

Comment: *I want INSERT the 300 or so from a_schools that aren't already in wp_terms without duplicating the ones already there.* Create unique index by `wp_terms (name)` and use `INSERT IGNORE ...` - the duplicates will be ignored and won't be inserted, `NOT EXISTS` not needed. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5bd13648e698297405d1e68080fd955d).

Comment: I tried what you posted on Fiddle.  It added all the rows from a_schools to wp_terms, duplicating the 100 or so already there.  

(It's actually wp_terms_copy - a backup data table - so I can easily undo this.)

Comment: @Jwrbloom as long as you add a unique index to `name` then a subsequent insert will not add duplicate rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=736c47a145712617c841f7ba9bf757a3

Comment: And I'm pretty sure wp_terms(name) is already set up as a unique key.

Comment: OK...it's not a unique key.  I mistook how that was listed in the table structure.  However, I can't alter the table because there are several duplicates because there are different relationships differentiated when JOINED with another table.  


Can't WHERE NOT EXISTS be implemented?

Comment: Can I assign what's created in CASE to an alias, such as schoolName, than add WHERE name != schoolName?